# JSON object as value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

In JSON, when an object is a value, what is the right way to write it?

```
var text ='{"phone":{"gtd": "080"}}';
```

OR

```
var text ='{"phone":"{gtd: 080}"}';
```

This may be a simple query. The reason i asked is because both JSON parse and stringify works on both. Which one is right?

Comment: Are you sure that `var text ='{"phone":"{gtd: 080}'}";` is a valid statement?

Comment: Should `... '}"` be `... "}'`?

Comment: the value of `gtd` is not equal. one is a string and one is a number (with an irritating leading zero).

Comment: @Robin - Sorry, it is actually - var text ='{"phone":"{gtd: 080}"}';

Comment: If there's a typo in your question please [edit] it, don't leave corrections in comments. Regarding the fact that `JSON.parse()` works on both, it may "work" in the sense of not giving an error, but it won't give the same result. The first one is what you (almost certainly) want.

Comment: And of course rather than storing a string containing JSON, create an actual object instead (if possible).

Comment: @FelixKling - You mean an array of objects? I am actually confused what are the diff ways to define a JSON? Can you pls point me to some article

Comment: One quick question, is an array of objects a JSON?

Comment: JSON is a textual data exchange format, like XML, YAML or CSV. A JavaScript object is a value of the JavaScript language. *" is an array of objects a JSON"* No. Maybe this helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON .

Answer (score 1):

if you put "{}" its not an object but a string, as pointed by @Felix Kling 080 is not a number actually, so it should be expressed as a string.

```
var text ='{"phone":{"gtd": "080"}}';
```

the name of the keys in the objects must to be strings thought

Comment: `080` is not a valid value (number) in JSON. Your example cannot be parsed.

Comment: @FelixKling - json.org says "A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array. These structures can be nested.". So 080 is valid right?

Comment: ohh i didn't noticed it was 0...80 i'm kinda sleepy already ... sorry.
you re right it should not parse

Comment: @FelixKling - You are right, 0 and then a . compulsory. else [1-9]. Thanks